# Where to store xml and file based information in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I have been storing these type of files in the `public` directory and now just thought that might not be the best place to store them since they can be called directly by going to the file itself www.domain.com/files/info.xml.

I have a route that calls them because I interact with the files in my controllers. So, where else can I store these types of files so they are not accessible to the user but I can still properly use them in my controllers?

Comment: it's PHP. php is not bound by your webserver's document root restrictions. you can put the files ANYWHERE on your server's drives that PHP has the filesystem permissions to reach. e.g. `/home/sites/example.com/public_html/...` for your site, and `/home/sites/example.com/xml/...` for your "private" stuff

Comment: I can create folders outside my domain root with no problems. I just don't know how to call those files from Laravel. An example is I call file_get_contents('files/info.xml') and I normally would just call ('../files/info.xml') to get out of that root and go back but it's causing errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can store these files anywhere. If you store them outside of your Laravel app, I would suggest creating a [configuration option](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration).

For example, in `config/app.php`:

```
'xml_path' => '/some/path/on/your/server'
```

Then you can reference this path anywhere in your Laravel app with:

```
 Config::get('app.xml_path');
```